# Modeling a collision phenomenon

Tags: fluid-dynamics, collision, simulations, software

I have a **single water droplet** (d~3 mm) which collides with a **solid particle** (d~2 mm) with a relative velocity around 10 m/s. After collision, particle rips the droplet and goes through it. Therefore, a film of water forms around the particle which should be like a hollow conic skirt behind it. (see Fig. 1 for drawing)

As you know, here we have different sources of forces applied to droplet like gravity, drag, friction, etc. that cause it to deform even before colliding with particle (Fig. 1-right) and we have a waste of energy due to collision as well. Is it possible to simulate this phenomena using Surface Evolver? (I mean is it capable of considering all the existing forces (energies) in simulation?)

[image]

Figure. 1- Schematic view of droplet and particle collision

Comment: I think this is a physics set up and a  legitimate request. I do not see an opinion expressed ! so I voted to reopen

Comment: @annav Thanks for your support. In fact, this type of questions plays an important role in how we attack the problems and helps us a lot in solving them. So, I believe we should be able to ask them in this forum.

Comment: I modified the question and now it is just a question regarding the capability of a particular software. Would you please unhold it?